# Discord Bot does not respond anymore

Tags: discord.py

Long question due to the code, but why does my bot not respond anymore? It's custom made for a friend and has been working for the past week or so, but now just does not respond. No errors are raised either. The only time it sends a message is when League Membership isn't in member roles and it sends the correct message. Otherwise, the bot does not respond.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import asyncio
import os
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members=True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
  membercount = len([m for m in guild.members if not m.bot])
  embedwelcome = discord.Embed(title="Your KFG Future Awaits You.", description=None, color=discord.Color.teal())
  embedwelcome.add_field(name="Things to do:", value=f"•Get Signed or claim a Franchise!\n•Make friends in the community!\n•Collect Rings\n•Make your way to the Super Bowl and win it all!\nWhat are you waiting for? Hurry up and get started!\n (You were member #{membercount}.)", inline=True)
  await member.send(embed=embedwelcome)
  print(f"{timestamp} - {member}")

@bot.command()
async def membercount(ctx):
  guild = bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
  membercount = len([m for m in guild.members if not m.bot])
  await ctx.send(f'KFG has {membercount} members.')
  print(f"{timestamp} - {ctx.author}")

@bot.command()
async def welcomemessage(ctx):
  guild = bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
  membercount = len([m for m in guild.members if not m.bot])
  embedwelcome = discord.Embed(title="Your KFG Future Awaits You.", description=None, color=discord.Color.teal())
  embedwelcome.add_field(name="Things to do:", value=f"•Get Signed or claim a Franchise!\n•Make friends in the community!\n•Collect Rings\n•Make your way to the Super Bowl and win it all!\nWhat are you waiting for? Hurry up and get started!\n (You were member #{membercount}.)", inline=True)
  await ctx.send(embed=embedwelcome)
  print(f"{timestamp} - {ctx.author}")
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print ("I'm online.")
  await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="KFG on top!"))
@bot.event
async def on_message(message, user:discord.Member=None):
  if "sign" in message.content:
      signer=message.author
      signee=message.mentions[0].mention
      signeeid=message.mentions[0].id
      server=bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
      teamsidslist=[801217912689393714, 801218094814986300, 801224104086208513, 801224243115196426, 801218409878519849, 801222227479625758, 801217334395011113, 801224558589378570, 801222379682005035, 801224701128343662, 801222478646476820, 801222668128747540, 801224835032285225, 801225075231031316, 801225211306967080, 801225374369185793, 801225554199576627, 801225700283121674, 801222743030104104, 801225798408732692, 801222852132995132, 801225991242514473, 801222923746148392, 801223092298186782, 801226082207924244, 801223311081996288, 801226241948647496, 801223486973542451, 801223635858882562, 801223809340276745, 801226427890139137, 801223952344416337]
      teamnames=['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Denver Broncos', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Houston Texans', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'New England Patriots','New Orleans Saints', 'New York Giants', 'New York Jets', 'Philidelphia Eagles', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'San Fransisco 49ers', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Tennesse Titans', 'Washington Football Team']
      teamemojis=['Arizona_Cardinals', 'Atlanta_Falcons', 'Baltimore_Ravens', 'Buffalo_Bills', 'Carolina_Panthers', 'Chicago_Bears', 'Cincinnati_Bengals', 'Cleveland_Browns', 'Dallas_Cowboys', 'Denver_Broncos', 'Detroit_Lions', 'Green_Bay_Packers', 'Houston_Texans', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Las_Vegas_Raiders', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Los_Angeles_Rams', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Minnesota_Vikings', 'New_England_Patriots', 'New_Orleans_Saints', 'New_York_Giants', 'New_York_Jets', 'Philidelphia_Eagles', 'Pittsburgh_Steelers', 'San_Francisco_49ers', 'Seattle_Seahawks', 'Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers', 'Tennessee_Titans', 'Washington_Football_Team']
      FO = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257262240235530)
      GM = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257315620749362)
      HC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257358751694848)
      AC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257421334904872)
      FA = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801255786062807090)
      Suspended = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=805818648802361426)
      roster=[]
      agency=[]
      teams=[]
      for rolesids in message.author.roles:
        if rolesids.id in teamsidslist:
          teams.append(rolesids.id)
          step2=str(teams)
          step3=step2.replace("[","")
          step4=step3.replace("]","")
          print(step4)
          step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
          print(step5)
          emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
          teamname=teamnames[step5]
          team = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))
      for agents in server.members:
        if FA in agents.roles:
          agency.append(agents.id)
      if signeeid not in agency:
          embedno = discord.Embed(title="Transaction Failed!", description=None, color=discord.Color.red())
          embedno.add_field(name="This Transaction Couldn't Be Completed.", value="This player is signed already! Have them demand from their team or get released.")
          await message.channel.send(embed=embedno)
      elif [FO, GM, HC, AC] in message.author.roles:
        for guys in server.members:
          if guys.id==signeeid:
            await guys.add_roles(team)
            await guys.remove_roles(FA)
            if Suspended in guys.roles:
              await message.channel.send("This player is signable, but is ineligible as they are suspended.")
        roster.append(guys)
        roster_size=str(len(roster))
        SignEmbed= discord.Embed(title="KFG Transactions", description=None, color=discord.Color.green())
        SignEmbed.add_field(name='Successful Transaction.', value=signee+" has been signed to the "+str(emote)+" "+teamname+"!")
        SignEmbed.add_field(name="Roster Size is now ", value=roster_size+'/20', inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(embed=SignEmbed)

bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_message3(message, user:discord.Member=None):
  if "I demand" in message.content:
      signer=message.author
      signee=message.mentions[0].mention
      signeeid=message.mentions[0].id
      server=bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
      teamsidslist=[801217912689393714, 801218094814986300, 801224104086208513, 801224243115196426, 801218409878519849, 801222227479625758, 801217334395011113, 801224558589378570, 801222379682005035, 801224701128343662, 801222478646476820, 801222668128747540, 801224835032285225, 801225075231031316, 801225211306967080, 801225374369185793, 801225554199576627, 801225700283121674, 801222743030104104, 801225798408732692, 801222852132995132, 801225991242514473, 801222923746148392, 801223092298186782, 801226082207924244, 801223311081996288, 801226241948647496, 801223486973542451, 801223635858882562, 801223809340276745, 801226427890139137, 801223952344416337]
      teamnames=['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Denver Broncos', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Houston Texans', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'New England Patriots','New Orleans Saints', 'New York Giants', 'New York Jets', 'Philidelphia Eagles', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'San Fransisco 49ers', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Tennesse Titans', 'Washington Football Team']
      teamemojis=['Arizona_Cardinals', 'Atlanta_Falcons', 'Baltimore_Ravens', 'Buffalo_Bills', 'Carolina_Panthers', 'Chicago_Bears', 'Cincinnati_Bengals', 'Cleveland_Browns', 'Dallas_Cowboys', 'Denver_Broncos', 'Detroit_Lions', 'Green_Bay_Packers', 'Houston_Texans', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Las_Vegas_Raiders', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Los_Angeles_Rams', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Minnesota_Vikings', 'New_England_Patriots', 'New_Orleans_Saints', 'New_York_Giants', 'New_York_Jets', 'Philidelphia_Eagles', 'Pittsburgh_Steelers', 'San_Francisco_49ers', 'Seattle_Seahawks', 'Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers', 'Tennessee_Titans', 'Washington_Football_Team']
      FO = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257262240235530)
      GM = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257315620749362)
      HC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257358751694848)
      AC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257421334904872)
      FA = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801255786062807090)
      roster=[]
      teams=[]
      agency=[]
      for rolesids in message.author.roles:
        if rolesids.id in teamsidslist:
          teams.append(rolesids.id)
          step2=str(teams)
          step3=step2.replace("[","")
          step4=step3.replace("]","")
          print(step4)
          step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
          print(step5)
          emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
          teamname=teamnames[step5]
          team = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))    
      if [teams] in message.author.roles:
        for guys in server.members:
          if guys.id==signeeid:
            await guys.add_roles(FA)
            await guys.remove_roles(team)
      if signeeid in agency:
        await message.channel.send('You are not signed and cannot demand!')
        roster.append(guys)
        roster_size=str(len(roster))
        SignEmbed= discord.Embed(title="KFG Transactions", description=None, color=discord.Color.green())
        SignEmbed.add_field(name='Successful Transaction.', value=signee+" has demanded from the "+str(emote)+" "+teamname+"!")
        SignEmbed.add_field(name=f"{str(emote)} {teamname}Roster Size is now ", value=roster_size+'/20', inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(embed=SignEmbed)
@bot.event
async def on_message2(message, user:discord.Member=None):
  if "release" in message.content:
      signer=message.author
      signee=message.mentions[0].mention
      signeeid=message.mentions[0].id74
      server=bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
      teamsidslist=[801217912689393714, 801218094814986300, 801224104086208513, 801224243115196426, 801218409878519849, 801222227479625758, 801217334395011113, 801224558589378570, 801222379682005035, 801224701128343662, 801222478646476820, 801222668128747540, 801224835032285225, 801225075231031316, 801225211306967080, 801225374369185793, 801225554199576627, 801225700283121674, 801222743030104104, 801225798408732692, 801222852132995132, 801225991242514473, 801222923746148392, 801223092298186782, 801226082207924244, 801223311081996288, 801226241948647496, 801223486973542451, 801223635858882562, 801223809340276745, 801226427890139137, 801223952344416337]
      teamnames=['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Denver Broncos', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Houston Texans', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'New England Patriots','New Orleans Saints', 'New York Giants', 'New York Jets', 'Philidelphia Eagles', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'San Fransisco 49ers', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Tennesse Titans', 'Washington Football Team']
      teamemojis=['Arizona_Cardinals', 'Atlanta_Falcons', 'Baltimore_Ravens', 'Buffalo_Bills', 'Carolina_Panthers', 'Chicago_Bears', 'Cincinnati_Bengals', 'Cleveland_Browns', 'Dallas_Cowboys', 'Denver_Broncos', 'Detroit_Lions', 'Green_Bay_Packers', 'Houston_Texans', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Las_Vegas_Raiders', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Los_Angeles_Rams', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Minnesota_Vikings', 'New_England_Patriots', 'New_Orleans_Saints', 'New_York_Giants', 'New_York_Jets', 'Philidelphia_Eagles', 'Pittsburgh_Steelers', 'San_Francisco_49ers', 'Seattle_Seahawks', 'Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers', 'Tennessee_Titans', 'Washington_Football_Team']
      FO = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257262240235530)
      GM = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257315620749362)
      HC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257358751694848)
      AC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257421334904872)
      FA = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801255786062807090)
      roster=[]
      teams=[]
      for rolesids in message.author.roles:
        if rolesids.id in teamsidslist:
          teams.append(rolesids.id)
          step2=str(teams)
          step3=step2.replace("[","")
          step4=step3.replace("]","")
          print(step4)
          step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
          print(step5)
          emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
          teamname=teamnames[step5]
          team = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))    
      if [FO, GM, HC, AC] in message.author.roles:
        for guys in server.members:
          if guys.id==signeeid:
            await guys.add_roles(FA)
            await guys.remove_roles(team)
        roster.append(guys)
        roster_size=str(len(roster))
        SignEmbed= discord.Embed(title="KFG Transactions", description=None, color=discord.Color.green())
        SignEmbed.add_field(name='Successful Transaction.', value=signee+" has been released from the "+str(emote)+" "+teamname+"!")
        SignEmbed.add_field(name="Roster Size is now ", value=roster_size+'/20', inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(embed=SignEmbed)

async def on_message5(message, member:discord.Member=None):
  if "promote" in message.content:
      signer=message.author
      signee=message.mentions[0].mention
      signeeid=message.mentions[0].id
      server=bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
      teamsidslist=[801217912689393714, 801218094814986300, 801224104086208513, 801224243115196426, 801218409878519849, 801222227479625758, 801217334395011113, 801224558589378570, 801222379682005035, 801224701128343662, 801222478646476820, 801222668128747540, 801224835032285225, 801225075231031316, 801225211306967080, 801225374369185793, 801225554199576627, 801225700283121674, 801222743030104104, 801225798408732692, 801222852132995132, 801225991242514473, 801222923746148392, 801223092298186782, 801226082207924244, 801223311081996288, 801226241948647496, 801223486973542451, 801223635858882562, 801223809340276745, 801226427890139137, 801223952344416337]
      teamnames=['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Denver Broncos', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Houston Texans', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'New England Patriots','New Orleans Saints', 'New York Giants', 'New York Jets', 'Philidelphia Eagles', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'San Fransisco 49ers', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Tennesse Titans', 'Washington Football Team']
      teamemojis=['Arizona_Cardinals', 'Atlanta_Falcons', 'Baltimore_Ravens', 'Buffalo_Bills', 'Carolina_Panthers', 'Chicago_Bears', 'Cincinnati_Bengals', 'Cleveland_Browns', 'Dallas_Cowboys', 'Denver_Broncos', 'Detroit_Lions', 'Green_Bay_Packers', 'Houston_Texans', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Las_Vegas_Raiders', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Los_Angeles_Rams', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Minnesota_Vikings', 'New_England_Patriots', 'New_Orleans_Saints', 'New_York_Giants', 'New_York_Jets', 'Philidelphia_Eagles', 'Pittsburgh_Steelers', 'San_Francisco_49ers', 'Seattle_Seahawks', 'Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers', 'Tennessee_Titans', 'Washington_Football_Team']
      FO = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257262240235530)
      GM = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257315620749362)
      HC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257358751694848)
      AC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257421334904872)
      staffroles = [GM, HC, AC]
      teams=[]
      roster=[]
      for rolesids in message.author.roles:
        if rolesids.id in teamsidslist:
          teams.append(rolesids.id)
          step2=str(staffroles)
          step3=step2.replace("[","")
          step4=step3.replace("]","")
          print(step4)
          step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
          print(step5)
          emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
          teamname=teamnames[step5]
          team = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))   
        if FO in message.author.roles:
         for guys in server.members:
           if guys.id==signeeid:
             await guys.add_roles(staffroles) 
        embedpromoted = discord.Embed(title='KFG Transactions', description=None)
        embedpromoted.add_field(name="The "+teamname+ " have made a promotion!", value="Congratulations to "+signee+" as the "+str(emote)+teamname+ " has promoted them to "+staffroles+".")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedpromoted)

@bot.event
async def on_message4(message, member:discord.Member=None):
  if "demote" in message.content:
      signer=message.author
      signee=message.mentions[0].mention
      signeeid=message.mentions[0].id
      server=bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
      teamsidslist=[801217912689393714, 801218094814986300, 801224104086208513, 801224243115196426, 801218409878519849, 801222227479625758, 801217334395011113, 801224558589378570, 801222379682005035, 801224701128343662, 801222478646476820, 801222668128747540, 801224835032285225, 801225075231031316, 801225211306967080, 801225374369185793, 801225554199576627, 801225700283121674, 801222743030104104, 801225798408732692, 801222852132995132, 801225991242514473, 801222923746148392, 801223092298186782, 801226082207924244, 801223311081996288, 801226241948647496, 801223486973542451, 801223635858882562, 801223809340276745, 801226427890139137, 801223952344416337]
      teamnames=['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Denver Broncos', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Houston Texans', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'New England Patriots','New Orleans Saints', 'New York Giants', 'New York Jets', 'Philidelphia Eagles', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'San Fransisco 49ers', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Tennesse Titans', 'Washington Football Team']
      teamemojis=['Arizona_Cardinals', 'Atlanta_Falcons', 'Baltimore_Ravens', 'Buffalo_Bills', 'Carolina_Panthers', 'Chicago_Bears', 'Cincinnati_Bengals', 'Cleveland_Browns', 'Dallas_Cowboys', 'Denver_Broncos', 'Detroit_Lions', 'Green_Bay_Packers', 'Houston_Texans', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Las_Vegas_Raiders', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Los_Angeles_Rams', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Minnesota_Vikings', 'New_England_Patriots', 'New_Orleans_Saints', 'New_York_Giants', 'New_York_Jets', 'Philidelphia_Eagles', 'Pittsburgh_Steelers', 'San_Francisco_49ers', 'Seattle_Seahawks', 'Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers', 'Tennessee_Titans', 'Washington_Football_Team']
      FO = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257262240235530)
      GM = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257315620749362)
      HC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257358751694848)
      AC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=801257421334904872)
      staffroles = [GM, HC, AC]
      teams=[]
      roster=[]
      for rolesids in message.author.roles:
        if rolesids.id in teamsidslist:
          teams.append(rolesids.id)
          step2=str(staffroles)
          step3=step2.replace("[","")
          step4=step3.replace("]","")
          print(step4)
          step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
          print(step5)
          emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
          teamname=teamnames[step5]
          team = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))   
        if FO in message.author.roles:
         for guys in server.members:
           if guys.id==signeeid:
             await guys.remove_roles(staffroles) 
        embedpromoted = discord.Embed(title='KFG Transactions', description=None)
        embedpromoted.add_field(name="The "+teamname+ " has made a demotion.", value='Tough luck for '+signee+' as they have been demoted from their spot as '+staffroles+'on the '+str(emote)+teamname+'.', inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedpromoted)

@bot.command()
async def rostercount(ctx, member:discord.Member=None):
      server=bot.get_guild(801206329049612288)
      teamsidslist=[801217912689393714, 801218094814986300, 801224104086208513, 801224243115196426, 801218409878519849, 801222227479625758, 801217334395011113, 801224558589378570, 801222379682005035, 801224701128343662, 801222478646476820, 801222668128747540, 801224835032285225, 801225075231031316, 801225211306967080, 801225374369185793, 801225554199576627, 801225700283121674, 801222743030104104, 801225798408732692, 801222852132995132, 801225991242514473, 801222923746148392, 801223092298186782, 801226082207924244, 801223311081996288, 801226241948647496, 801223486973542451, 801223635858882562, 801223809340276745, 801226427890139137, 801223952344416337]
      teamnames=['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Baltimore Ravens', 'Buffalo Bills', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears', 'Cincinnati Bengals', 'Cleveland Browns', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Denver Broncos', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Houston Texans', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Las Vegas Raiders', 'Los Angeles Chargers', 'Los Angeles Rams', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'New England Patriots','New Orleans Saints', 'New York Giants', 'New York Jets', 'Philidelphia Eagles', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'San Fransisco 49ers', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Tennesse Titans', 'Washington Football Team']
      teamemojis=['Arizona_Cardinals', 'Atlanta_Falcons', 'Baltimore_Ravens', 'Buffalo_Bills', 'Carolina_Panthers', 'Chicago_Bears', 'Cincinnati_Bengals', 'Cleveland_Browns', 'Dallas_Cowboys', 'Denver_Broncos', 'Detroit_Lions', 'Green_Bay_Packers', 'Houston_Texans', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Indianaoplis_Colts', 'Jacksonville_Jaguars', 'Kansas_City_Chiefs', 'Las_Vegas_Raiders', 'Los_Angeles_Chargers', 'Los_Angeles_Rams', 'Miami_Dolphins', 'Minnesota_Vikings', 'New_England_Patriots', 'New_Orleans_Saints', 'New_York_Giants', 'New_York_Jets', 'Philidelphia_Eagles', 'Pittsburgh_Steelers', 'San_Francisco_49ers', 'Seattle_Seahawks', 'Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers', 'Tennessee_Titans', 'Washington_Football_Team']
      roster=[]
      teams=[]
      roster=[]
      step2=str(teams)
      step3=step2.replace("[","")
      step4=step3.replace("]","")
      print(step4)
      step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
      print(step5)
      emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
      teamname=teamnames[step5]
      team = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))
      for guys in server.members:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
      roster_size=(len(roster))      
      teamlist = discord.Embed(title=+str(emote)+teamname+"'s roster count:")
      teamlist.add_field(name=roster_size, value=str(emote)+teamname+f"'s roster count - brought up by {ctx.author}")
      await ctx.send(embed=teamlist)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(f"Some idiot raised an error at {timestamp} - it was {ctx.author}: {error}")
    raise error

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv('kfgbottoken'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create more than one `on_message` event. Only the last one will work. Also, you have to add `bot.process_commands(message)` to the last line of `on_message` event. Otherwise it prevents commands from running.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

All you have to do is putting all your `on_message` events in just one.

Comment: process_commands is a coroutine, it should be awaited

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I see you on all my questions lol. Thanks so much for the help. Nurqm, thanks for helping too.

Comment: By the way, it's still not responding.

Comment: You don't have more than 1 `on_message` event, right?

Comment: Not anymore. It now says unexpected unindent. If you can, add my discord so I can send the code. .ax#1234

Comment: You can update your question with only the related code.

Comment: It does not let me with the reason that I went over the character limit.

Comment: Well, you can remove the irrelevant code so that only the relevant part remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228438/discussion-between-toohard-and-nurqm).